# Wicket and spring how to configure such that it does not look for applicationContext

Tags: spring, inversion-of-control, integration, wicket

I am using wicket 6.19 and spring 4.0.3

I have configured spring such that i do not need applicationContext.xml.

I have added the appropriate listener to my web.xml but upon deploying my spring-wicket application have been shot down with a message saying it cannot find applicationContext.xml

A bit of searching turned up the following: AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext

So clearly i need to tell my application that it is an application based configuration and what class takes care of this. Anyone got any idea how i configure this within a wicket-spring environment ?

In my ? extends webapplication class in my init i have:

```
 getComponentInstantiationListeners().add(new SpringComponentInjector(this));
```

My web.xml

```
 <listener>
       <listener-class>
           org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoadListener
       </listener-class>
 </listener>
```

Nothing else seems relevant to this issue which is the fact it keeps trying to find applicationContext.xml despite my spring configuration being exclusively handled by annotations.

Comment: Please can post relevant code and config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use `@Configuration` based config?
If YES then take a look at Wicket 7.x wicket-examples:

https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/7bcf9236b0fe8a86f53603c22390a75dda4fad7b/wicket-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/examples/spring/common/SpringConfig.java

https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/7bcf9236b0fe8a86f53603c22390a75dda4fad7b/wicket-examples/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml#L825-L833

Comment: following the link regarding web-inf gave me the context param i was looking for. thanks.